# What should I install on 12.04 for a school?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, 32-bit

I am in charge of installing Linux on all Windows XP laptops in my school. I chose Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I am not sure what I should install on it. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Remember that having installed Ubuntu (and added Ubuntu Restricted Extras, as @Alan suggested), you have all the software in the Ubuntu Software Centre available to you. Also, if these are old computers, you probably want to look at [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) instead of Ubuntu. Lubuntu *is* Ubuntu, but modified for low-spec computers; it will run much faster.

Comment: These latptops have about 500 MB of RAM, so should I put Lubuntu on them? How can I solve the internet problem, they don't give an option to connect wirelessly to the internet

Comment: You should definitely go for Lubuntu. Ubuntu will run far too slowly on that small amount of memory. Lubuntu has all the software available to Ubuntu through its Lubuntu Software Centre. Internet connectivity is another question altogether. If wireless is not available, there is a way to download packages and updates on one computer that has an Internet connection, and pass them to the other computers using USB, CD or DVD. You'll have to search [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) for help on this, because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All package that mentioned above is basic packages. It also depend the target of using (ex. which subject required using laptop), age of students and other criteria.

Comment: This is in a High School, the librarian did not tell me what class would be using the laptops, but they are a teachers personal set. I have to do this for different classes and each mobile lab is different because some are old and some are new.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could put Ubuntu restricted extras (mainly for playing MP3), VLC (can read most formats of video and audio), Google Chorme (kids love this browser), and Microsoft core fonts (some teachers make kids type with the Times New Roman font.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/), the free education oriented operating system for kids of *all* ages.

IMHO [Epoptes](http://www.epoptes.org/) looks promissing.

Answer (score 1):

For kids you can install GCompris, Tuxpaint, Tuxtyping, Tux of Math Command. 
In the software center you can see a lot of apps for kids and youngs.

Answer (score 0):

In the repos
ubuntu-edu-preschool
ubuntu-edu-primary
ubuntu-edu-secondary
ubuntu-edu-tertiary

look also at
ubuntustudio-audio
ubuntustudio-audio-plugins
ubuntustudio-font-meta
ubuntustudio-graphics
ubuntustudio-photography
ubuntustudio-publishing
ubuntustudio-recording
ubuntustudio-video

Comment: Why those packages?

Comment: For School users

Comment: For School users, the UbuntuStudio apps will be more for the older Kids, have a look at the apps that these install ( in synaptic, right click on one of the above, then Properties, then click on Dependencies Tab, which will show what will be installed ) These will install all the dependent apps

Comment: I was asking because simply listing packages in your answer isn't helpful at all. You should give a description of the functionality of each package.